# How do I tidy up ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a scenario whereby I have to detect if certain fields in an Angular form are valid and dirty.

I am currently doing this using ng-class which works perfectly. However, I am ending up with a massive expression which looks really messy and sloppy in the html. Below is an example:

```
data-ng-class="{'component-is-valid' : 
form.firstName.$valid && form.firstName.$dirty && form.lastName.$valid  && form.lastName.$dirty && form.emailAddress.$valid &&     form.emailAddress.$dirty && form.mobileNumber.$valid &&   form.mobileNumber.$dirty}"
```

As you can see, this is quite long.

Is there anyway I can extract this so that I retain the flexibility of ng-class but also free up my DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the whole form validation in one hit with `$ctrl.form.$valid` instead of checking all, as `Keegan G` correctly states.

That said, there can be cases where your ngClass logic get's quite large and unreadable.

An alternative approach I often adopt is to move all logic to the controller. e.g.

Template:

```
<div ng-class="$ctrl.componentClasses()"></div>
```

Controller:

```
controller: function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.isValid = function() {
    // do all your checking here, ultimately it should return a bool

    return [Boolean];
  }

  vm.componentClasses = function() {
    return {
      'my-class-name': vm.isValid()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a function on your scope that accepts your form object or input fields and returns the boolean you're describing above: `ng-class="{'component-is-valid': checkValidity(form)}"`